# Best practice with angular cicd jenkins and docker

Tags: angular, docker, jenkins

I am setting up cicd pipeline for my angular ui and confused if the build commands should run in jenkins or in the docker build.

I have seen in few places where the build commands are run in jenkinsfile and only the dist folder is copied in docker images and in somewhere elese, they do build as well in docker. What is a good practice around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been thinking about the same question and have no definite answer. Both of the approaches work. There's one advantage in the building in Dockerfile approach, though. If we consider the following Dockerfile sample format:

```
FROM node:20-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

<continues>
```

Docker creates a separate layer for the `npm install` that is cached. After that the subsequent builds do not need to create that, only the one with the full source code.

With Jenkins either the `npm install` has to be done with every build, or the npm environment should persist between different builds. Neither are as elegant solutions as with Dockerfile.